# Python, pandas loops works only in the last item

Tags: python, pandas, rstudio

edit : my apology : I find the issue, I am using Rstudio to run the code, which mess up something, I just try it from the console and it is working fine

I know, I am doing something silly but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, I built this script that read a zip file, do some transformation and write a final csv, but for some reason, only the last file got written
the script is fully reproducible, the source files are located in the link below if you want to try and debug it.

```
files = os.listdir(os.curdir)
files = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.zip')]
print(files)
for x in files:
     path_file = os.path.join(curDir ,x)
     print(path_file)
     source = pd.read_csv(path_file,
     skiprows=1,
     usecols=["DISPATCH","1" ,"SETTLEMENTDATE", "RUNNO","INTERVENTION","CASESUBTYPE","SOLUTIONSTATUS","NONPHYSICALLOSSES"],
     dtype=str)

     source.rename(columns={'1': 'version'}, inplace=True)
     source.query('version=="2"')

      ################ Extract UNIT, SETTLEMENTDATE,DUID,INITIALMW AND EXPORT TO CSV
     df_unit=source
     df_unit=df_unit.query('DISPATCH=="DUNIT" or DISPATCH=="TUNIT"')
     #Make first row a header
     df_unit.columns = df_unit.iloc[0]
     df_unit = df_unit[1:]
     #create a conditional column
     df_unit.loc[df_unit['DUNIT'] == 'TUNIT', 'INITIALMW1'] = df_unit['INTERVENTION']
     df_unit.loc[df_unit['DUNIT'] == 'DUNIT', 'INITIALMW1'] = df_unit['INITIALMW']
     df_unit.drop(columns=['RUNNO','2','INTERVENTION','INITIALMW','DISPATCHMODE'],inplace=True)
     df_unit.rename(columns={'INITIALMW1': 'INITIALMW','DUNIT': 'UNIT'}, inplace=True)
     df_unit=df_unit.query('SETTLEMENTDATE!="SETTLEMENTDATE" and INITIALMW !="0"')
     df_unit["INITIALMW"] = pd.to_numeric(df_unit["INITIALMW"])
     df_unit['SETTLEMENTDATE']=pd.to_datetime(df_unit['SETTLEMENTDATE'])
     df_unit.head()
     df_unit.to_csv(x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.csv',float_format="%.4f",
     index=False,date_format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',compression='gzip')
     print(path_file)
```

> **EDIT:** I added list files:
>       ['PUBLIC_DAILY_201906040000_20190605040502.zip',
>       'PUBLIC_DAILY_201906050000_20190606040501.zip',
>       'PUBLIC_DAILY_201907140000_20190715040502.zip']
>   
> The files are downloaded from [here](http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Current/Daily_Reports/).

Comment: Can you paste `files`? how does it looks like?

Comment: @vbrises please see edit

Comment: @Mim: I recognized, that in your call to `to_csv` you don't add the path. Is it possible that the file actually is written to another directory? Have you already checked the directory, which is returned by `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: Probably, you can just replace `x` by `path_file` in the `to_csv` line if you want to write the file to the same directory as the input file.

Comment: @jottbe, same results

Comment: Have you tried to print the new file name already? If you don't get an exception, it should create a file, even if the file is empty (in which case it should at least contain the headers)

Comment: @jottbe no, it create only 1 file, I expect three files

Comment: provide the whole path while writing the file

Comment: can you try with this `df_unit.to_csv(str(x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + ".csv"),  ... )`. Also what is the file name, which is actually getting created?

Comment: @vbrises, same results did you run it at your computer, I gave the source files

Comment: @Mim I ran it, I changed `os.curdir to os.getcwd()` and it created different csv's.

Comment: @vbrises can you post the code, and I will try it

Comment: @vbrises sorry my bad, I find the issue, I use rstudio and something went wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is working for me. Probably you only have one downloaded zip file in the current directory, or actually you are **invoking jupyter notebook or python script from the incorrect directory**. You can print `os.getcwd()`. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with the code. All the zip files has to be in the same directory from where you this code is getting run either through python script or jupyter notebook.

```
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
files = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.zip')]
print(files)
for x in files:
    path_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd() ,x)
    print(path_file)
    ...
    ... 
    df_unit.to_csv(x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.csv',float_format="%.4f",
    index=False,date_format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',compression='gzip')
    print(path_file)
```